# Pass a map as a param to an Elasticsearch groovy script

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, parameters

I've indexed user's lat / lon as one of the fields for a document in Elasticsearch. Now, the initial requirement was to sort users by the input distance, for which, I used below sort:

```
"sort": [
    {
        "_geo_distance": {
            "user.location": {
                "lat": 39,
                "lon": -83
            },
            "order": "asc",
            "distance_type" : "plane"
        }
    }
]
```

However, now the requirement has been changed and, we have added user's office code to the index. For few of those codes, the distance is calculated using Google's driving distance API (which is not currently possible in Elasticsearch) and when sorting the users, these driving distances have to be considered instead of Elasticsearch calculated distance.

One of the alternate is to pass in a map of user.officecode and the driving distance as a parameter to the script and look-up this map before performing the distance miles calculation. If the user.officecode for the user is present in the map then return it's value else, go-ahead with the Elasticsearch distance calculations.

The point I'm stuck at is, in what format should the map be passed in. How do I build the map externally and set it as parameter.

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.7 and using Transport Client to connect to Elasticsearch cluster.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm using below Elasticsearch sort:

```
"sort": {
    "_script": {
        "script": "(office_code==null || office_code.isEmpty() || lot_code.indexOf(doc['user.officecode'].value) == -1 || office_code_distance==null || office_code_distance.isEmpty())?(doc[distanceFieldName].isEmpty()?null:(Math.round(doc[distanceFieldName].distanceInMiles(lat,lon)*100)/100.0)):office_code_distance.get(office_code.indexOf(doc['user.officecode'].value))",
        "type": "number",
        "params": {
            "distanceFieldName":"user.location",
            "lat": 39,
            "lon": -83,
            "office_code": ["259000"],
            "office_code_distance": [57]
        },
        "order" : "asc"
    }
}
```

Not sure it this is a correct solution, but, it's working for me.